# How to create a dialogue box to enter the filepath

Tags: vbscript

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\New folder _1")
```

I am using this code to read the folderpath. objFolder will store the path of the folder. 
In the same way, when i run the total code, i need to get a dialogue box where 
i should be able to enter the folderpath.

Comment: Are you also very new to search engines? https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vbscript+dialog+folder

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBScript to open a dialog to select a filepath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559775/vbscript-to-open-a-dialog-to-select-a-filepath)

Comment: Did you mean Browse4Folder or Browse4File ?

Comment: No, i dont want to browse a file, I need to store a filepath.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett, thanks for reply..  It serves for selecting a file, I need to select a folder. pls suggest

Comment: I suggest you look at [the link in my first comment](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vbscript+dialog+folder) and pick a solution from there.

Answer (score 0):

This script to Browse4File : [browse files in folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28594331/browse-files-in-folder/28596069#28596069)

and this code for Browse4Folder :

```
Option Explicit
Dim RootFolder
RootFolder = Browse4Folder
MsgBox RootFolder,VbInformation,RootFolder
'**********************************************************************************************
Function Browse4Folder()
    Dim objShell,objFolder,Message
    Message = "Please select a folder in order to scan into it and its subfolders"
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0,Message,1,"c:\Programs")
    If objFolder Is Nothing Then
        Wscript.Quit
    End If
    Browse4Folder = objFolder.self.path
end Function
'**********************************************************************************************
```